# Difference between styles and control templates

Tags: silverlight

I'd like to know what the differences between an Style (for a control) and a control template are.
Best regards,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 6):

A style controls the individual properties of a control.  For instance, a button style can say, "For every button, use this background."  A style is changing a single property on a control.

A control template is actually handling how the control displays its bound data.  Instead of saying, "I want to override a control's properties," you are assembling together other smaller controls into a single control that can present different views of the bound data.

Previously in WinForms, if you wanted to write a custom list box (say that had an icon next to each item), you had to inherit from the ListView control and override the painting methods.  This involved a ton of experimentation - huge pain.  With WPF templates, you can use XAML to construct smaller controls together and bind them to different properties of the parent control.  You are actually defining the Visual Tree for the control.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx) article for an in-depth explanation by Charles Petzold.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and the link to the article. I'll take a look at it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine your control is a house.

A `Style` is conceptually similar to putting down a new carpet and painting the walls. The house itself is still the same but its outward appearance is different.

A `ControlTemplate` is the equivalent of knocking down a wall or adding a conservatory. The actual *structure* of the house has changed.

Use a `Style` when you want to change the outward appearance of the control E.G. it's background colour or the thickness of it's border.

Use a `ControlTemplate` when you need to change the underlying structure of the control. This is useful when you want to change the layout of certain aspects of a control. A good example is in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24106/Creating-an-Outlook-Navigation-Pane-by-Restyling-a) article which re-templates a `TabControl` to look like the navigator from Microsoft Outlook.